# Magento 2 : How to add custom parameter in invoice template email

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, invoice

I want to add a custom parameter in the invoice template and display that template.
so please give me any solution on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an observer for passing custom parameters to invoice template. Try the below one in your custom module.

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="email_invoice_set_template_vars_before">
    <observer name="vendor-add-custom-field-data-invoice" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\Invoice\EmailTemplateVars"/>
</event>
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/Observer/Invoice/EmailTemplateVars.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\Invoice;

class EmailTemplateVars implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $helper;

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $transport = $observer->getTransport();
       $order = $transport['order'];

       $transport['my_custom_field'] = "test";        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response but not working for me..

Comment: did you clear cache after creating module and setup upgrade??

Comment: thanks, I have run command but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="email_invoice_set_template_vars_before">
  <observer name="vendor-add-custom-field-data-invoice" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\Invoice\EmailTemplateVars"/>
</event>
```

**Vendor/Module/Model/Observer/Invoice/EmailTemplateVars.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Observer\Invoice;

class EmailTemplateVars implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $helper;
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $transportObject = $observer->getEvent()->getData('transportObject');
       $order = $transportObject->getData('order');
       $transportObject->setData('my_custom_field', 'test');
    }
}
```